# Ubuntu Compatibility

Tags: cpu, ram, compatibility

I'm in the process of building a computer for a customer who has requested Ubuntu 13.04 to be installed could someone tell me if the following components are compatible.

- CPU: Pentium G2020
- mobo: Gigabyte GA-H61MA-D3V
- RAM: 4GB 1333MHz DDR3

Answer (score 1):

I can say for sure that the Gigabyte GA-H61 will work out of the box. No problems there. For the CPU and RAM they will work correctly, specially if you are using 13.04 since it is the latest (They would have worked with older version of Ubuntu up to 12.04 if I am not mistaken).

So yeah, you will have full compatibility with all of that.

For reference here are other questions:

[Which hardware manufacturers are more friendly to Ubuntu, besides Intel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169059/which-hardware-manufacturers-are-more-friendly-to-ubuntu-besides-intel)

[Does 32-bit PAE with more than 4GB RAM improve speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60155/does-32-bit-pae-with-more-than-4gb-ram-improve-speed/60183#60183)

[Hardware compatibility on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276960/hardware-compatibility-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/277271#277271)

[What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)